# Best case performance of quicksort (tilde notation)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

My professor stated that the best case for quicksort is when the split is balanced (i.e. when the pivot is always the element in the middle).

Now the complexity of best-case quicksort can be determined by using a recurrent relation, as folows:

```
T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + partitioning(n)
```

In the next step he states:

thus `= ~n * log2(n)`

Could someone elaborate how exactly you can calculate this. I've searched around a lot, but all explanations are in big-Oh notation or don't really explain how the recurrency is solved/calculated.

Comment: That's not how [tilde notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/316964) is used. Are you looking for big-O or tilde?

Comment: @amit Tilde. In this book, tilde is defined as Big-O but without dropping the constant factor. I.e: 5x^4 + 3x^2 = ~5x^4, but O(x^4)

Comment: The problem is, quick-sort is not ~nlogn in tilde notation... (Well, it might be if you specify you count only some specific operation, but I still doubt it). It's going to be ~C*nlogn, for some constant C

Comment: Well yes, quicksort is ~1,39log2(n) on average. But I was wondering about the best case. Not really sure what you're pointing out here.

Comment: I'm pointing, (1) You cannot continue the calculation without first analyzing `partitioning(n)`. (2) `partitioning(n)` is unlikely to be exactly `~n` (which is the only one that will give you exactly `~nlog_2(n)`). (3) Personally, I find tilde notation rubbish, since it's too platform dependent to worth anything (differenrt performance are expected for example on machines that supports vector operations, comparing to those who don't), but that's just my POV, and I don't try to force it on others.

Comment: Well, I don't really have a choice as my professor won't correct your answer on the exam if you write it in anything other than tilde notation :-) But what if we actually DO assume that `partitioning`  is exactly `n` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to address [Tilde Notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316964/working-with-the-tilde-notation-asymptotic-analysis) in this answer, with the assumption of `partitioning(n)` is itself `~n`, which means it runs in time `G(n) = n + C`.

In this case, complexity function of best case is:

With base clause of `T(1) = 1+C`

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + (n+C)
```

Claim: For all `n>0`:

```
T(n) = n(1+logn) + (2n-1)C
```

Proof by induction.

Base clause: For `T(1)` the claim holds as the base.

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + (n + C)
T(n) = 2(n/2 log(n/2) + n/2 + (n-1)C) +(n + C) //induction hypothesis
T(n) = nlog(n/2) + n + (2n-2)C + n  + C
T(n) = nlog(n/2) + nlog(2) + n + (2n-2)C + C
T(n) = nlog(n/2 * 2) + n +(2n-2+1)C
T(n) = n(logn+1) + (2n-1)C
```

Since `T(n) = nlogn + (2C+1)n - C`, we can conclude it is indeed `~nlogn`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer comes from the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form).

The recurrence relation for the best-case running time of Quicksort is:

`T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Θ(n)`

Master theorem generalizes a recurrence relation to the form:

`T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`

Comparing the two equations:

`a = 2`

`b = 2`

`f(n) = Θ(n)`

Since `f(n) = Θ(n)`, from Case 2 of the Master theorem:

```html
If f(n) = &theta;(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>), then T(n) = &theta;(n<sup>log<sub>b</sub>a</sup>lg(n))
```

So, the time complexity of Quicksort in the best-case reduces to

`T(n) = Θ(n lg(n))`

EDIT:
If you are asking why it is in tilde notation `~n * log2(n)` and not in Big-O notation, it is because in your case, the goal must be to create an approximate model of the running time (without ignoring the constants if there were any) instead of developing an upper bound on the complexity. Moreover, tilde notation is very useful for predicting performance whereas Big-O notation is not.

Comment: As I do understand this explanation, I was looking for the tilde notation and how this is derived.